# Ember js access different model data from template

Tags: javascript, mongodb, ember.js

Im using the sane stack with mongo db. I'm fairly new to emberjs. I'm using ember 0.2.5 and sails 0.11.0 and mongodb.

I have a game route, controller and model that I can properly access from the game template. I also have a separate player route, controller, model, template setup that I can also access and manipulate properly.

A game has two players, and the player has a logo. Given I have the game data which contains each player id, I basically want to do get the player logo using the player id and display that in the game template.

Ive tried a few things, this is my last attempt to put that logic in the game controller.

```html
//model/game.js

import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    home_player: DS.attr('string'),
    away_player: DS.attr('string'),
    players: DS.hasMany('players'),
});



//Here's the logic of what I want to achieve

playerLogo: function(playerName){
  for (player in players) 
    if player.name == playerName
    return player.logo_url);
}
```

I've searched a bit I don't see an straight forward answer to this (or a solution I understand).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your model definition of `Game` has set relationship `players: DS.hasMany('players')` without setting `{ async: true }`. I assume that you are familiar with the consequences and you set your backend to send `game` object with nested `players` relationship. If not, I'll get to it back later.

Assuming that your backend is sending the data properly you can do it like this:

```
game.get('players').findBy('id', idYouHave).get("logo_url"); # you can find by 'name' also
```

Remember to always use `#set` and `#get` when working with Ember/DS objects. You cannot query or set properties directly.

Ok, but if it's not a problem, but you rather defined the relationship without knowledge what `async` means, let's take a look. `async` means that Ember should fetch the related models by ids when they will be needed. Thus, all you get from backend is `game` object with `player_ids` table (e.g. `player_ids: [1, 2]`). These related players are not accessible initially - they still need to be fetched by ember, but only when explicitly needed. Therefore you would have to change your logic to use promises:

```
game.get('players').then(function(players) { 
  players.findBy('id', idYouHave).get("logo_url");
});
```

Remember though, that changing to `async` is a huge change that in case of big application can take some work to perform. You need to change your API too. However, it is more intuitive and more easy in maintenance than not using `async`. In long term, when you get a lot of related models, it has better performance.